# Right justifying an image to separated lines

Tags: formatting, titles, wrapfigure

I'm trying to figure out how to position the logo (pictured) to the right of the three lines of text.

My attempt at achieving this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{1.95\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.6]{logo.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}
\text{A thesis submitted for the degree of}
\textit{Master of Science}
April 2022
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: We don't have the original image, don't know what your document class and page dimensions are, etc., so it's hard to help. However `\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{1.95\textwidth}` doesn't make any sense. That sets the figure width to almost twice the width of a line of text, so of course there'll be no room for anything next to it. Decrease that. If needed add `\hfill` to the start of other lines to push them to the right. If that doesn't do it, post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Since you aren't really wrapping the text around the image, wrapfig is overkill.  Just put the text into a \parbox or minipage.  You may need \raisebox to align the tops.